# Rails builder.collection_select with join table not saving the join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Contents model that belongs_to a Projects model. Currently when a user goes to add a new Content, they must select the project it belongs to in the form:

**_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= f.fields_for :project do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Associate...") %>
    <% end %>
```

This is correctly populating the dropdown. But if a user selects a Project and hits save, it does not get saved/associated to the Content.

Here's my **contents_controller.rb**:

```
class ContentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_content, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /contents
  # GET /contents.json
  def index
    @contents = Content.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /contents/1
  # GET /contents/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /contents/new
  def new
    @content = Content.new
  end

  # GET /contents/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contents
  # POST /contents.json
  def create
    @content = Content.new(content_params)
    if @content.save 
      redirect_to @content, notice: 'Content created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /contents/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contents/1.json
  def update
    if @content.update(content_params)
      redirect_to @content, notice: 'Content updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contents/1
  # DELETE /contents/1.json
  def destroy
    @content.destroy
    redirect_to contents_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_content
      @content = Content.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def content_params
      params.require(:content).permit(:name, :category, :function, :status, :url, :description, projects_attributes: [ :id, :name ])
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `associations` and rest of the `form` code?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this to my **project.rb**:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :productline`

And then this in **projects_controller.rb**:

```
def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :image, :stage, :slug, :description, :content_id)
    end
```